# how to handle this case if fetchmail fetches spam from yahoo, and postfix does not deliver because host does not exist

Tags: postfix, email

I have fetchmail collecting from yahoo and passing the mails to the local postfix server.
If I have a 4xx Error , because for example the sender domain does not exist, fetchmail will try to pas this email forever to postfix and postfix will reject it forever with

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]: 450 4.1.8 <office@orchic2.us>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from=<office@orchic2.us>
```

first question:
how do I have to setup fetchmail to fist of all act from a local host I have set-up
fetchmail.localdomain[127.0.0.7]
in order that the logfile looks like this:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from fetchmail.localdomain[127.0.0.7]: 450 4.1.8 <office@orchic2.us>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from=<office@orchic2.us>
```

for this I have setup /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
127.0.0.7       fetchmail.localdomain   fetchmail
```

second question:
how can I setup fetchmail to try a limited nr of times to pass the mail to postfix and after this to skip it?

Comment: Hmmm, what do you mean in this sentences `how do I have to setup fetchmail to fist of all act from a local host I setup called fetchmail.localdomain[127.0.0.7]`?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I avoid the whole local mailserver and have fetchmail running from my crontab and deliver straight to old-school procmail which in turn calls SpamAssassin, anti-virus and before filtering and dropping my mail in the correct Maildir:

```
poll pop.example.com with proto pop3:
        user "me@example.com" there has password "password"
        is me here and wants ssl nokeep mda "/usr/bin/procmail -t /home/me/.procmailrc"
```